# Spaceless tag inside script block

Tags: twig

I'm trying to inline this so the rendered page isn't 100,000 lines long.
It seems the spaceless tag does nothing here.

Input:

```
{% for log in logs -%}
    {% spaceless %}
        {
            id: {{ log.id }},
            description: '{{ log.description }}'
        },
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endfor -%}
```

Expected Output:

```
{id:17186,description:'Test Log'},
{id:17187,description:'Test Log 2'},
```

Output:

```
{
    id: 17186,
    description: 'Test Log'
},
{
    id: 17187,
    description: 'Test Log 2'
},
```

Comment: From the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html): "Use the `spaceless` tag to remove whitespace *between HTML tags*, not whitespace within HTML tags or whitespace in plain text."

Answer (score 2):

Like the [documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/spaceless.html) says, you can "use the `spaceless` tag to remove whitespace *between HTML tags*, not whitespace within HTML tags or whitespace in plain text."

You can instead [control whitespace](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#templates-whitespace-control) e.g. like this:

```
{% for log in logs -%}
    {
        {{- 'id' }}: {{ log.id }},
        {{- 'description' }}: '{{ log.description }}'
    {{- '},' }}
{%- endfor %}
```

The above produces this:

```
{id: 17186,description: 'Test Log'},{id: 17187,description: 'Test Log 2'},
```

The downside is that the Twig code is much uglier.

Here's an alternative using [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#string-interpolation):

```
{% for log in logs -%}
    {
        {{- 'id' }}: {{ log.id }},
        {{- 'description' }}: {{ "'#{log.description}'" -}}
    },
{%- endfor %}
```

```
{id: 17186,description: &#039;Test Log&#039;},{id: 17187,description: &#039;Test Log 2&#039;},
```

The Twig code looks now better, but notice that single quotes got converted to `&#039;`. You may or may not want to do something about that.

You could also do like the documentation suggests and use a third-party library like Tidy.